# i need tips to write ajax for asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

It makes me in trouble when I write jQuery Ajax calls for each task in my whole application. I write jQuery Ajax calls to update the interface after a specific event, such as updating a dropdown list when another dropdown list selection changes.

I need the fastest way to handle Ajax requests across my application and to avoid code repetition.

```
 // code sample to ajax request which I used
function onChange(bookid) { 
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("books","subject")',
        data : { bookid: bookid},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) { 
          alert('success');
          //do whatever you want
        },
        error: function(result){
        }
    }); 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an approach that would simplify these kind of ajax call to update interface after specific events, using asp.net mvc 4, I would suggest that you look into the awesome [awesome](http://awesome.codeplex.com/) set of helpers.

**Be assured that it's a very easy to learn set of helpers.**

I encourage to go to the [Live demo](http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/) and play with it for a while. You will rapidly realize its great potential.

Then an example with master - slave dropdown list (first element on the default demo page).

Here is the code that goes into the view:

```
Cascading using binding to Parent:<br />
<%:Html.Awe().AjaxDropdown("Category")
             .Url(Url.Action("GetCategories","Home")) %>

<%:Html.Awe().AjaxDropdown("ChildMeal")
            .Url(Url.Action("GetMeals","Home"))
            .Parent("Category") %>
```

The first dropdown is an ÀjaxDropDown`named`Category`. It is filled by executing an action method called`GetCategories`found on a controller called`HomeController` (in this example these are meals categories).

Note that Awesome uses some conventions in certains cases. For example if we had limited the first AjaxDropDown declaration to `<%:Html.Awe().AjaxDropdown("Category")%>`then the Awesome will assume that we would fill the dropdown from an action method called GetItems and it would expect to find it on a controller called **CategoryAjaxDropDownController**. But since we have specified the url with the corresponding action, it would look for the specified action method on a controller called **SPECIFIED_NAME+Controller** (in this example Home**Controller**)

The second's name is ChildMeal, it's parent is the Category ajax drop down and it is filled when the selected element is changed in the Category drop down, and when that happens it is filled by executing the GetMeals action method from the HomeController controller.

Here is the code for the action methods in the `HomeController`

```
public ActionResult GetCategories(int? v)
{
    var items = Db.Categories
        .Select(o => new SelectableItem(o.Id, o.Name, v == o.Id));// value,     text, selected
    return Json(items);
}

public ActionResult GetMeals(int? v, int? parent)
{
    var items = Db.Meals.Where(o => o.Category.Id == parent)
        .Select(o => new SelectableItem(o.Id, o.Name, v == o.Id));// key,     text, selected
    return Json(items);
}
```

As you can see from the return object t**he JSON handling complexity is managed by Awesome and it all becomes transparent to the developer** (you just have to invoke `Json(items)` to have it done.

The Db object provides the datas. You may use a class that inherits from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`in order to load datas from a database.

You have many other similar components (such as the AjaxRadioList, the AjaxCheckBoxList, the AjaxList, the AutoComplete component, ...) among many very interesting rich components.

I suggest that you go to the live demo, play with it, see the various examples and the source codes, then you try to create your first awesome project.

Answer (score 1):

well jQUery's ajax call's about as fast as your going to get - there is not a lot of overhead on the client side at all .

as far as extra code .. for each call:

```
function onChange(bookid) { 
      $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",                           // not needed - default GET
        url: '@Url.Action("books","subject")',
        data : { bookid: bookid},
        dataType: "json",                 // not needed - jQuery will guess
        success: function (result) { 
          alert('success');
          //do whatever you want
        },
        error: function(result){     // not needed if you're leaving empty
        }
    }); 
};
```

could be

```
  $.get('@Url.Action("books" , "subject")' , { bookid: bookid}, function(result){
      alert(result);
  });
```

Comment: ok if the parameter was complex object and have more than 20 property ?

Comment: then pass in the javascript object

Comment: with it's properties ?

Comment: i think i'll takes more time !